# Java Enhanced For-Loop only stores the last value

Tags: java, spring

I have this List

```
List<Task> = []
```

inside Task there is a methode that returns a `Map<String, Object>`. This is how it looks like this Map `{releveId=20, releveId=30}` I'm retrieving only the values `20 & 30` and store them into a variable `X`.

Now I have a class called `TaskDto`. This class will carry all the data I need.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table
@Entity
public class TaskDto {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int taskId;
  private int releveBancaireId;
  private String variableName;
  private String variableTypeName;
  private String proccessesName;
  private String id;
  private String assignee;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private int priority;
  private String processDefinitionId;
  private String processInstanceId;
  private Date createTime;

}
```

One of the fields `TaskDto` has is `releveId`.

So while looping over the `List<Task>` and storing Map value in `X`
When I try to do this : `taskDto.setReleveId(X)` this stores only the last one in our case is `30` where it should store both 20 & 30

This is my for loop:

```
for (Task taskLoop: tasks) {
    Map<String, Object> variables = taskLoop.getProcessVariables();
    System.out.println("showing variables " + variables); // this displays {relevebancaireId=20} {relevebancaireId=30}
    for (Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry: variables.entrySet()) {
        X = stringObjectEntry.getValue().toString();
        System.out.println("displaying X " + X); // this displays 20 & 30
    }
}
```

taskDto.setReleveBancaireId(Integer.parseInt(X));

Expected return:

```
showing task dto TaskDto(releveBancaireId=20, variableName=relevebancaireId, variableTypeName=long,)
showing task dto TaskDto(releveBancaireId=30, variableName=relevebancaireId, variableTypeName=long,)
```

actual return:

```
showing task dto TaskDto(releveBancaireId=30, variableName=relevebancaireId, variableTypeName=long,)
showing task dto TaskDto(releveBancaireId=30, variableName=relevebancaireId, variableTypeName=long,)
```

**Long explanation:**

this service will get all tasks that are currerntly uncompleted by Activiti workflow. What I'm doing here is to display all the Tasks

```
   public List<TaskDto> getTasks(String assignee) {
    ProcessDefinition processDefinition = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().singleResult();
    List<HistoricVariableInstance> historicVariableInstance = historyService.createHistoricVariableInstanceQuery().list();
    ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
    TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();

// here I'm specifying the proccess
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskDefinitionKey("sid-4131471b-5de5-4760-97c7-c651b27c0258").includeProcessVariables().orderByTaskCreateTime().desc().list();

// and here I'm trying to retrieve releveBancaireId from a Map to set it to TaskDto
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      Map<String, Object> variables = task.getProcessVariables();
      for (Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry : variables.entrySet()) {
      releveBancaireId = stringObjectEntry.getValue().toString();
      }
    }
    for (HistoricVariableInstance variableInstance : historicVariableInstance) {
      variableName = variableInstance.getVariableName();
      variableTypeName = variableInstance.getVariableTypeName();
    }

// here I'm retrieving all the tasks and set every field in TaskDto and every Task has a different releveBancaireId. That is what this question is all about.

    List<Task> taskList = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(assignee).list();
    String finalVariableName = variableName;
    String finalVariableTypeName = variableTypeName;
     return taskList.stream().map(task ->{
      TaskDto taskDto = new TaskDto();
// this line I'm setting the above releveBancaireId to this dto
      taskDto.setReleveBancaireId(Integer.parseInt(releveBancaireId));
      taskDto.setVariableName(finalVariableName);
      taskDto.setVariableTypeName(finalVariableTypeName);
      taskDto.setProccessesName(processDefinition.getName());
      taskDto.setId(task.getId());
      taskDto.setAssignee(task.getAssignee());
      taskDto.setName(task.getName());
      taskDto.setDescription(task.getDescription());
      taskDto.setPriority(task.getPriority());
      taskDto.setProcessDefinitionId(task.getProcessDefinitionId());
      taskDto.setCreateTime(task.getCreateTime());
      return taskDto;
    }
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

// Retrieve assigned tasks

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/tasks")
  public ResponseEntity<List<TaskDto>> getTasks(@RequestParam String assignee) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(processService.getTasks(assignee), HttpStatus.OK);

  }
```

those pictures shows the output of the Map & the taskDto:

[image]

[image]

Another example See only the last value is getting stored:

[image]

I tried to make setter inside for loop but still ovveride it , also I tried to make TaskDto a entity and persist it to MySQL just to give a try if this has something about persisting but also in MySQL table has the last value persisted I don't know where the problem is.

My apology for the long explanation, but to simplify the problem is that for loop is ovveriding all the values and store only the last one, that's the problem. I really need this help I've tried many solutions but nothing

Comment: Okay, but first loop. X should passed to setReleveBancaireId and the second loop should pass another value, finally should display the first and the second not only the second, am I wrong ?

Comment: In your example code, X (minor side note: it should be lowercase, but not important right now) is set once per item in your map, but passed to your DTO only at the end of the for loop since the set its outside the for loop. Meaning that it will set the last value of X. You will probably need one DTO to store each `releveBancaireId` (That depends on the actual usage of the DTO)

Comment: Can you share snippet of code Jetto!

Comment: I would need a more complete piece of code. I don't know where the other properties of the DTO are set not where it is returned. The 'easy' fix would be to put the set inside the nested for loop, but that would produce the same result as the releveBancaireId would be overriden in every loop.

Comment: It looks like your map implementation has different values stored for the same key. This is not how a map is supposed to work, but you always show the "contents" of your map as comments. Please show us some [mre] and not just some loose snippets.

Comment: I have updated my question included full code, sorry for the long explanation but really need your help about this

Comment: `for (Entry<String, Object> stringObjectEntry : variables.entrySet()) {
      releveBancaireId = stringObjectEntry.getValue().toString();
      }`
Here you are completion your map iteration , so always its sets the last value. May be look at your indentation properly